# Set dynamic ConnectionString Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I developed Asp.net application with Entity Framework and now i need to change entity connection string at run time.I tried following way.

```
public class DataLayer(){

static DataLayer()
{
((EntityConnection)_dbEntity.Connection).StoreConnection.ConnectionString =    GetConnectionString();

//GetConnectonString() returns "user id=xxxx;password=xxxx;database=xxxx;server=xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
}

static DBContext _dbEntity = new DBContext();
//other codes
}
```

And I checked following links too.Still I couldn't change it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738533(v=vs.90).aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/8a89a728-6c8d-4734-98cb-11b196ba11fd

Comment: Static context in ASP.NET application = [failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653009/entity-framework-and-connection-pooling/3653392#3653392).

Comment: i changed that one still i cant change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer.I apply this dbcontext to a Entity datasource of a grid.So it create context at runtime it was fixed.So I changed that one.

```
 protected void EntityDataSource1_ContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var dp=new DBContext();
        e.Context = dp;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change connection string of existing context. If you want to control connection string at runtime you must pass connection string to `DbContext` or `ObjectContext` constructor.

Btw. as I already mentioned in comment - you must not use static context in ASP.NET. You should never use static context at all. Your application will not work correctly if you will continue with static context.

Comment: Yep i tried that one too. I got following error. "Keyword not supported: 'user id'." It means connection string is not supported for entityconnection.I tried above links in question too for that.

Comment: If you are using EDMX you must use valid [entity connection string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx) format. What you are passing is not entity connection string format.